# SQL: IS NULL fails when trying to update values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am currently trying to update some table values and I am stuck with a particular instance.

The situation is that I have a main table `DBO.MAIN_INTERACTIONS` that I join with an external table. Based on the below WHERE values I would then like to update the main database values. KCMACustomer.DBO.DATA_EXT_GREEN_ENR is a table that is linked to one particular product and my idea was to select and update the table rows of MAIN that do not have a connection with this GREEN_ENR table. That's why I put the `EXT.NUMBER_OF_ACCOUNTS IS NULL`.

So the rows I am trying to retrieve will have no match on this JOIN condition `'MAIN.GENID = EXT.GENID'`. Is this what makes my update query fail? and would there be a better way to get the rows that have no connection with KCMACustomer.DBO.DATA_EXT_GREEN_ENR (the main table values are all the same, so I can't differentiate there)

Extra info: the second query does work, probably because there is a succesful `'MAIN.GENID = EXT.GENID'` join

```
UPDATE 
    MAIN
SET 
    STATE_CODE='S8',
    STATE_NAME='Reminder 1',
    OLD_STATE='S4',
    MODIFIED_DT = @NOW
OUTPUT INSERTED.ID, 0, 'AUTO-STATE','business','Doc.expected -> Reminder 1',INSERTED.CAMPAIGNID, @NOW,'S4','S8' INTO KCMACustomer.DBO.DATA_EBW_FFC_LOG_STATES
FROM KCMACUSTOMER.DBO.MAIN_INTERACTIONS AS MAIN
JOIN KCMACustomer.DBO.DATA_EXT_GREEN_ENR AS EXT
ON MAIN.GENID = EXT.GENID
WHERE 
    MAIN.STATE_CODE='S4'
AND 
    MAIN.TYPE_DEMAND='S4'
AND 
    EXT.NUMBER_OF_ACCOUNTS IS NULL
AND 
    DATEDIFF(hh, MAIN.MODIFIED_DT, @NOW)>=168
AND
    MAIN.PRODUCT IN (@HELLO4YOU, @COMFORT_PACK, @PREMIUM_PACK)
```

In this case the `'MAIN.GENID = EXT.GENID'` will have a match and it does update the records I want

```
UPDATE 
        MAIN
    SET 
        STATE_CODE='S8',
        STATE_NAME='Reminder 1 eID',
        OLD_STATE='S4',
        MODIFIED_DT = @NOW
    OUTPUT INSERTED.ID, 0, 'AUTO-STATE','business','Doc expected -> Reminder 1 eID',INSERTED.CAMPAIGNID, @NOW,'S4','S8' INTO KCMACustomer.DBO.DATA_EBW_FFC_LOG_STATES
    FROM KCMACUSTOMER.DBO.MAIN_INTERACTIONS AS MAIN
    JOIN KCMACustomer.DBO.DATA_EXT_GREEN_ENR AS EXT
    ON MAIN.GENID = EXT.GENID
    WHERE 
        MAIN.STATE_CODE = 'S4'
    AND 
        DATEDIFF(hh, MAIN.MODIFIED_DT, @NOW)>=120 
    AND
        MAIN.PRODUCT IN (@HELLO4YOU, @COMFORT_PACK, @PREMIUM_PACK)
    AND
        EXT.NUMBER_OF_ACCOUNTS IS NOT NULL
    AND
        MAIN.DEMAND_DT > '2020-05-27 00:00:00'
```

Comment: This is not MySQL syntax so the code would simply not run.  Please tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: removed the tag

Comment: So  which DBMS product **are** you using?

Comment: Tbh I don't know the particular name, I am mainly a front-end developer who has to do basic stuff like this from time to time. My first guess is Postgresql.

Comment: It's definitely not Postgres. What does `select version();` or `select @@version;` give you?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP4-OD) (KB4091266) - 11.0.7469.6 (X64) 
 Feb 28 2018 17:47:20 
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor)

Comment: with @@version .

Comment: JOIN is INNER JOIN. You want to use LEFT JOIN. And it is better to check for EXT.GENID is NULL to check as you said `if MAIN that do not have a connection with this GREEN_ENR`

Comment: Thank you Gabriel, I will try it

Comment: you can add it as an answer and I'll green tick it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JOIN` implies an `INNER JOIN`
The use case you described requires a `LEFT JOIN`.

You will need to change your query so that it uses

```
LEFT JOIN KCMACustomer.DBO.DATA_EXT_GREEN_ENR AS EXT 
ON MAIN.GENID = EXT.GENID
```

I also suggest to test the `NULL` condition of the same column you use in the join condition. So instead of doing

```
 EXT.NUMBER_OF_ACCOUNTS IS NULL
```

check if

```
 EXT.GENID IS NULL
```

You are more familiar with your data so it might not have an impact on your query. But the record from MAIN could be linked to a record in EXT, but that record could have NUMBER_OF_ACCOUNTS NULL.
However, checking on the GENID of the EXT table would ensure that a link was not found when trying to find a matching record in main.